How to upload video locally in ckeditor5 in vue?
I first time use ckeditor. Initially i can upload and delete images. after i try to upload video files locally and delete also. i can upload video file but not reflected at inside editor. Here my code:
<script setup>
function InsertVideoPlugin(editor) {
  editor.ui.componentFactory.add('insertVideo', (locale) => {
    const view = new ButtonView(locale)
    view.set({
      label: 'Insert Video',
      tooltip: true,
      withText: true,
    })
    view.on('execute', () => {
      const fileInput = document.createElement('input')
      fileInput.type = 'file'
      fileInput.accept = 'video/*'
      fileInput.click()
      fileInput.onchange = (e) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0]
        if (file) {
          const loader = { file: Promise.resolve(file) }
//here no problem for uploading. 
          const uploadAdapter = editor.plugins.get('FileRepository').createUploadAdapter(loader)
          uploadAdapter
            .upload()
            .then((response) => {
              const videoUrl = response.default
              editor.model.change((writer) => {
                const selection = editor.model.document.selection
                    // problem here
                    // i can get videoUrl but dont reflected
                if (!selection.isCollapsed) {
                  const videoElement = writer.createElement('media', {
                    url: videoUrl,
                  })

                  writer.insert(videoElement, selection.getFirstPosition())
                } else {
                  console.warn('No valid selection to insert media')
                }
              })
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error('Upload failed:', error)
            })
        }
      }
    })
    return view
  })
}

const editorConfig = ref({
  plugins: [
   ...,
    MediaEmbed,
    MediaEmbedEditing,
    MediaEmbedUI,
  ],
  toolbar: {
    items: [
      ...,
      'insertVideo',
      'mediaEmbed',
      'blockQuote',
      'codeBlock',
    ],
  },

  mediaEmbed: {
    previewsInData: true, // Enables previews in the editor data
   
  },
 ...
})

const onEditorReady = (editorInstance) => {
  InsertVideoPlugin(editorInstance)
}
</script>

<template>
  <ckeditor
    :editor="ClassicEditor"
    :config="editorConfig"
    v-model="editorData"
    @ready="onEditorReady"
  ></ckeditor>
</template>

Here successfully uploaded files(video also). Here videoUrl - is video link. I think problem when createElement.
